# Unique rows per day

Tags: sql-server, group-by, datepart

I need to get a list of users email addresses that logged into my website over the course of a day.

The list may contain duplicate email addresses but not more than one per day.

I need to obtain this data for a week.

I have a table that contains records for each successful login as follows..

```
[ID], [LOGIN_EMAIL], [LOGIN_TIME]
```

The following query gets me the whole data set for the week but I need to filter it to one email address per day and get the entire list for the week?

```
SELECT LOGIN_EMAIL 
FROM USER_LOGINS 
WHERE LOGIN_TIME IS BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192924/sql-distinct-for-2-fields-in-a-database

Comment: Do you need the actual email addresses, or just a count of the number of distinct ones?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT   LOGIN_EMAIL,
         DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, LOGIN_TIME), 0) AS LOGIN_DATE
FROM     USER_LOGINS 
WHERE    LOGIN_TIME BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
GROUP BY LOGIN_EMAIL, 
         DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, LOGIN_TIME), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `group by Day([LOGIN_TIME]), [LOGIN_EMAIL]`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOGIN_EMAIL,LOGIN_TIME FROM USER_LOGINS WHERE LOGIN_TIME IS BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE
```

you may need to chnge LOGIN_TIME to Day format

Answer (score 0):

```
   select DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), LOGIN_TIME, 102) as LogDate, login_email 
   from user_logins WHERE ...
```